# Token Introspection endpoint, "invalid client credentials"

Tags: connected-apps, accesstoken

I'm working with a connected app which is using the JWT Bearer Token flow for API access. Generating access tokens and using them for API calls is working fine. When I use the Token Introspection to check the status of an access token I'm getting an "invalid client credentials" error.

```
request:{
  path:"",
  headers:{
    'Content-Type':"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    Accept:"application/json"
  },
  parameters:{
  },
  endpoint:"https://REDACTED_DOMAIN.lightning.force.com/services/oauth2/introspect",
  body:{
    token:"****",
    client_id:"****",
    client_secret:"****",
    token_type_hint:"access_token"
  }
},
service:null,
operation:null,
status:401,
reason:"Unauthorized",
body:{
  error:"invalid_client",
  error_description:"invalid client credentials"
},
```

According to the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oidc_token_introspection.htm&type=5) I need to pass in a `client_id` and `client_secret` value for authorization. The documentation does not clearly state where these values are defined on the connected app.

- For the `client_id` I'm using the "Consumer Key" listed on the connected App's "Manage" page. The example appears to be in the same format.
- For the `client_secret` I'm using the "Consumer Secret" listed on the connected App's "Manage" page. The example does not appear to be in the same format however there is no value on the App's "Manage" page that matches the format in the example.

The connected app has the setting "Introspect All Tokens" enabled.

Anyone have any experience with this and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: You're on the right track. Please edit your question and provide full request/response trace (all HTTP headers + body) with redacted keys.

Comment: Maybe has to do with the payload encoding. Make sure there are no invalid characters in those 2 values (client_id and client_secret) when you send the request. I've experienced this behavior when client_id has non URL safe characters.

Comment: The "token" parameter does contain an exclamation point (!) however I'm passing it in the body of the POST request, not as a GET parameter. I updated the question to include more details on the request/response

Comment: @Mark Deleting your comment and writing it up as the answer is recommended.

Comment: Done and done..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. My parameters were correct however the endpoint is very strict about the ContentType. My application was using a JSON ContentType and payload which it did not recognize. After changing the ContentType to application/x-www-form-urlencoded it accepted the params and validated the token